# Can the energy transferred to a system as heat be saved completely as mechanical energy of the system?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, work

If energy is transferred to a system (as heat or work) and there is no transfer of energy from this system, then the energy transferred to the system will be saved as one of the forms of energy of the system i.e. increase the energy of the system (which may be thermal energy, mechanical energy, chemical energy etc). If the energy transfer was as work then this can be completely be saved as either mechanical energy of the system or thermal energy of the system (we won't consider other energy of the system). But if the energy transfer was as heat then this can be saved completely as the thermal energy of the system but the energy transferred cannot be completely be saved as mechanical energy. Is this the case or can the complete energy transferred to the system as heat can also be saved as mechanical energy of the system? (As mechanical energy can be completely be changed to work easily).

Comment: No offence 1, but what does the second law say? No offence 2, paragraphs would make it easy to read.

Comment: It depends on what you define as being included in your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each type of energy is associated with a certain amount of entropy. For example, the mechanical energy, electricity, and laser light have low entropy. Other types of energy are not "entropy free", especially the heat energy.

Entropy can increase, but cannot decrease during the process of conversion of one type of energy to another. You can convert one low-entropy energy type to another and back with minimal technical losses, because this process does not conceptually change the entropy of the system. For example, you can convert electricity to the mechanical energy and back with little losses, such in hybrid electric cars.

You can also convert a low-entropy energy to a high-entropy energy. For example, an electric heater converts electricity to heat 100%. The same way friction converts the mechanical energy to heat 100%.

However, you cannot convert 100% of a high-entropy energy, such as heat, to a low-entropy energy, such as electricity or mechanical energy. This would contradict the law of the entropy increase. The total amount of entropy in the system must not decrease. For this reason, the efficiency of such a conversion would be limited. For example, the efficiency of an internal combustion engine in cars is only about 40% with the rest just heating the outside air.

So, to answer your question, we can store the heat energy in an insulated heated object, but we cannot completely convert heat to the mechanical energy. Accorging to the [Carnot's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot%27s_theorem_(thermodynamics)) of thermodynamics, the maximum efficiency of a heat engine is:

$$\eta=1-\dfrac{T_c}{T_h}$$

Where $T_c$ is the temperature of the environment and $T_h$ is the temperature of the heater.

See [Energy Conversion Efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_conversion_efficiency) and [Thermal Efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_efficiency)

Comment: Canceled the anonymous downvote. But some clarification in your answer is required. For e.g. what is the entropy associated with "... mechanical energy, electricity, and laser light..."? Also the statement "... you cannot convert 100% of a high-entropy energy, such as heat, to a low-entropy energy..." will be correct only when you add that no increase in entropy somewhere else results. For the same reason "... total amount of entropy in the system must not decrease..." must have "universe" instead of "system".

Comment: @Deep Thanks so much! Of course, my answer is not a physical thesis, but simply phrased in practical terms for a layman to understand. I agree with all your points and believe that my answer doesn't contradict any of them. My main point is that the mechanical energy, electricity, and coherent light are the sources of energy that are essentially entropy free, so ideally you could convert one to another with no loss. However, in reality, there always is friction and electrical resistance, and the light coherence is limited, so some entropy increase does happen during the conversion. [Continued]

Comment: @Deep ... [Continued] So hopefully this answers your first comment. On your second comment, I am not quite sure what you mean. The efficiency of a steam engine cannot be made 100% (unless at the absolute zero temperature, which is impractical) no matter where the entropy increase is, no? I even gave the Carnot's formula. On the last point, I meant a closed system, of course. Although for the purposes of this question, the point seems clear enough that heat has entropy while electricity essentially doesn't and so converting heat 100% to electricity would be an obvious  entropy decrease.

Comment: @safesphere Considering heat as the transfer of low-quality energy and work as the transfer of high-quality energy does answer my question. Thank you.  Usually, in literature heat and work are both given as means of transfer of energy.Heat transferred to a system (call it system A) is like the thermal energy transferred from another system(call it system B) to this system(system A)..and [Continued]

Comment: [Continued] so can increase the thermal energy  of system A by the amount of energy transferred, spontaneously, but cannot increase other forms of energy of system A, spontaneously. So in short energy transferred as heat can only increase the thermal energy of the system.

Comment: @safesphere: This answer would be correct when considering a cyclic process. If the energy transfer as heat was done to a system undergoing a reversible isothermal process the entire heat transferred could be saved as mechanical energy(As entire heat transferred would be converted to work).Here the entropy generation would be zero. Would I be wrong in saying this

Comment: A reversible isotermal process keeps the temperature constant. So (1) how would you transfer heat without changing the temperature and (2) how would you convert heat to the mechanical energy without changing the temperature? I guess my point is mostly practical. In hybrid cars the mechanical energy and electricity are constantly converting to each other with minimal losses, but with gasoline engines we get at most 40% of what we pay for and the rest of the heat just goes out one way to warm up the outside air with no good way of getting this energy back.

Comment: Can you give a reference for *"Each type of energy is associated with a certain amount of entropy."*, or at least explain where this association is supposed to come from in standard statistical physics?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I knew it wasn't the best way to phrase the idea, but then again I can hardly imagine that a smart guy like you doesnt know what I'm talking about. What's entropy? A logariphm of the number of states in the system? Something like that, no? So if you have one body moving, that's one state, the entropy is zero. But if you have a gazillion bodies moving, like molecules of gas, then entropy is far from zero. What's wrong in this argument? If you can think of phrasing this better, why don't you help improving the answer instead of spending 20k of your reputation for downvoting others?

Comment: The point is that entropy is the number of *microstates* associated to a particular *macrostate* of a statistical system. Just having a gazillion particles is not enough, you need to not know and *not care* in what state exactly each particle is in to have a notion of entropy. The only sense in which I can see "types of energy" being associated to low/high entropy is whether increasing that type of energy for the macrostate increases the number of available microstates or not,

Comment: but I haven't really seen this distinction being made in statistical mechanics, and it is not obvious to me the correspondence between the types of energy and low/high entropy is as you say. In particular, heat is not a state function - between two states with fixed entropy differences there are processes which take more or less heat than the others to complete, yet the resulting entropy difference remains the same, so I can't even confirm the intuitively sort-of plausible association of heat energy to high entropy.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I agree in a way that I also would not be able to write a formula, but for any practical real life purpose (aside perhaps for elaborate scientific setups), heat is a high entropy energy while electricity and mechanical are virtually no-entropy types of energy. This is exactly why we have hybrid cars and heat pumps along with low efficiency gasoline engines, real life things that cannot be understood by people without understanding the entropy difference among different types of energy. And also why a hydrogen fuel cell is better (no heat) that just burning hydrogen as gasoline.